# Hibernate integration on a Spring web application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have been following [this tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/index.html) on the Springsource website in order to have basic knowledge of Spring. Everything went good.

Now, I would like to integrate Hibernate to this little application I wrote following this tutorial. I found documentation on different websites (including hibernate's website) but I still have a few questions before starting.

I read some stuff about JPA and I can use it as an abstraction layer on top of hibernate but I don't really understand what for.

In addition, I read somewhere that there is two ways to use hibernate, the first one is annotations and the second one is using javax.persistance, I am right?

Is there some recent documentation about how to use hibernate in an existing spring web application, as well as the different ways to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA is a specification, hibernate can be considered as a implementation of the JPA spec.

You can use either annotation for mapping file with hibernate.

The following tutorials are better:

[Hibernate Tutorial Vaannila](http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-tutorial/hibernate-tutorial.html)

[Hibernate Tutorial Mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/)

Answer (score 1):

JPA is a standard, Hibernate is an implementation, but has other/additional functionality.

The [Spring Reference manual's section on ORM integration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate) covers Hibernate. There are also scores of tutorials and demos, like [here](http://www.nabeelalimemon.com/blog/2010/05/spring-3-integrated-with-hibernate-part-a/), but there are a bunch of other ones, and more recent ones.